# Does reissuing an SSL certificate invalidate the previously-issued certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, revoked

I used the "reissue certificate" functionality at a SSL certificate vendor (RapidSSL, FWIW) to get a new certificate - in doing so, I created and used a new private key and pass phrase.

Will the re-issuance of this certificate cause the previously-issued certificate to become invalid? If so, how long does that take?

Comment: If a certificate is re-issued, before I can update my servers will the users be affected by the invalidated certificate?

Answer (score 10):

Not automatically, for RapidSSL.  For other vendors and/or certificate grades, it may be be automatic.

RapidSS don't automatically invalidate a certificate when it is re-issued, according to their [Certificate Practice Statement](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=rapidssl+certificate+practice+statement&aq=f&oq=rapidssl+certificate+practice+statement&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l5.5863&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  This would be a function of how much you pay for the certificate.

In section II.B.5 of the [currently-google-able CPS](http://www.rapidssl.com/resources/pdfs/RapidSSL_CPS_v1.0_6-27-05_FINAL.pdf):

> GeoTrust will not revoke a Certificate previously issued following a
>   refund or reissue request. A request for a refund or reissue of a
>   Certificate will not be treated as a request by the Subscriber for
>   revocation of a Certificate previously issued by GeoTrust unless the
>   Subscriber follows the procedures for requesting revocation as stated
>   at Section III.I. of this CPS.

In section III.I it says:

> Certificate revocation is the process by which GeoTrust prematurely
>   ends the Operational Period of a Certificate by posting the serial
>   number of the Certificate to a Certificate Revocation List. A
>   Subscriber shall inform GeoTrust and promptly request revocation of a
>   Certificate:
>
> - whenever any of the information on the Certificate changes or becomes obsolete; or
> - whenever the Private Key, or the media holding the Private Key, associated with the Certificate is Compromised; or
> - upon a change in the ownership of a Subscriber's web server.  Subscriber shall state the reason(s) for requesting revocation upon submitting the request.

Elsewhere it minimally promises that revoked certificates will be added to the CRL 'at least once a week'.

Reading the Certificate Practice Statement of any purchaser of SSL certificate services is a good thing for a buyer to do.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they will revoke the old certificate.

The way that SSL revocations works is that, inside the certificate, the vendor places a URL where the client (e.g. browser) should check if the certificate is still valid (called a CRL).

So there is no hard and fast answer to this, it depends on the client. In some cases, like [this article](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/02/google-strips-chrome-of-ssl-revocation-checking/), it suggests it won't be checked at all.

Comment: It's not automatic that the certificate issuer will put the old certificates on a CRL.